# Cant remove jslint from sublime text 2

Tags: php, javascript, sublimetext2

I installed jslint a few weeks ago usig the package installer and never got it to properly work. When saving a file down no matter the extension(.php, .css, .html, etc.) I get this error

```
[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd:  [u'node', u'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Roaming\\Sublime Text 2\\Packages/JSLint/linter.js', u'--sloppy', u'--indent', u'2', u'--node', u'--nomen', u'--vars', u'--plusplus', u'--stupid', u'--todo', u'C:\\wamp\\www\\child-themes\\wp-content\\themes\\genesischild\\style.css']]
[dir:  C:\wamp\www\child-themes\wp-content\themes\genesischild]
[path: C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Ruby200-x64\bin]
[Finished]
```

I decided to remove it but everytime I restart sublime it reappears. I have deleted over 20 times the last couple of weeks and it keeps re installing itself. Any way to completely remove jslint from sublime text 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to remove it from package control. To do this either go to your package control settings `Preferences -> Package Settings -> Package Control -> Settings - User` and remove it from the `installed_packages` list. You can also search the command palette for `Package Control: Remove Package`. Package Control will install any package in the installed list if it is not on your machine automatically. This is nice to have when moving from machine to machine.

Comment: Thank you very much! I removed it using the `Package Control: Remove Package` this took only a few seconds. I restarted sublime text and it is not showing. Thanks again.